# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'select'

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I know this was asked before but I think the answer is specific to my script. This is my first time creating a proc and using Table Variables. I am unpivoting a table and generating a GridView from that for a user control. I need to then take the check boxes on the user control and pivot that to update the original table. 
The last part I need is to create this proc.

I am sure there are a couple ways to do this but this is an Azure Database and I am so close to finishing it making this option work. Anything would help.

Thanks,

```
USE [OST]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [mgt].[InsertPageSecurityMapping]    Script Date: 3/30/2016 11:30:55 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE procedure [mgt].[UpdateAlerts] 
(   
    @pkDistro int
    ,@intAlerts int
    ,@vchrCustomer varchar(100)
)

as
begin

--create a table variable of the unpivoted mgt.tblDistro table 
DECLARE @unpvtDistroTemp TABLE
(
    pkDistroID int,
    vchrCustomer varchar(100),
    intAlerts int
)

INSERT INTO @unpvtDistroTemp (pkDistroID, vchrCustomer, intAlerts)
(
SELECT pkDistroID, vchrCustomer, intAlerts 
FROM 
(SELECT pkDistroID, intComcast, intCableVision, intHearst, intCharter FROM mgt.tblDistro) mtd 
UNPIVOT (intAlerts FOR vchrCustomer IN (intComcast, intCableVision, intHearst, intCharter)) as unpvtTable
)

--check to see if the alerts are a 1 or 0 and update the table
if @intAlerts = 1
begin
    UPDATE @unpvtDistroTemp
    SET intAlerts = 1
    WHERE pkDistroID = @pkDistro AND @vchrCustomer
select 1
end

if @intAlerts = 0
begin
    UPDATE @unpvtDistroTemp
    set intAlerts = 0 
    WHERE pkDistroID = @pkDistro AND vchrCustomer = @vchrCustomer
select 0    
end

UPDATE mgt.TblDistro 
SET @vchrCustomer = (SELECT @vchrCustomer
    FROM @unpvtDistroTemp
    PIVOT
    (MAX(intAlerts)
    FOR vchrCustomer IN (intComcast, intCableVision, intHearst, intCharter)) as pvtTable
    WHERE pkDistroID = @pkDistro)

end 



GO
```

Comment: By the way, it is saying the error is around the 'SELECT' in the UNPIVOT.

Comment: WOW! Stupid mistake... I forgot to put the bool lean expression in my first IF statement. Sorry for the post.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE pkDistroID = @pkDistro AND vchrCustomer = @vchrCustomer
```

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference.